# How can I do this CONCAT compare in Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a autocomplete search field that users can use to find different pricelists.

The fields I want to compare in the database are:
* Brand name (string)
* Modelyear (string)
* Type of vehicle (int)

Type of vehicle is either 0, 1 or 2. Which is (caravan, mobilehome, trailer)

So the user might search for:
"Adria 560 2005 Caravan"

My first idea was to do a CONCAT LIKE compare.
WHERE CONCAT(brand,modelyear,type) LIKE '%Adria 560 2005 Caravan%'

But the problem is that type of vehicle is an integer so it would compare "Caravan" with 0,1,2.

Could I somehow convert the int to strings which I compare against?

Comment: search on how to `JOIN` tables

Comment: Your approach will not work if your user searches for e.g. "2005 caravan". Is it by design?

Comment: I was going to do it like this '%Adria% %560% %2005% %Caravan%'

Answer (score 0):

Preprocess the search string with PHP str_replace() or preg_replace() function, before searching. This will enable you to support multiple languages in a simple way in the future, if you ever decide to do this.
Ideally you should be separating the WHERE conditions so that the database system can optimise the query however it wants:

```
WHERE type=0 AND CONCAT(brand,modelyear) LIKE '%Adria 560 200[4-6]%'
```

etc.

Comment: -1 for this awful suggested hack. I would be glad to explain further if you post a question about this. +1 for advising separate `WHERE` conditions.

Comment: Where is the awful hack? I tried doing something like this and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

If the table name for vehicle type is vehicleType the query would be similar to the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM vehicle v
INNER JOIN vehicleType vt on vt.vehicle_type_id = v.vehicle_type
WHERE concat_ws(v.brandName,v.modelYear,vt.vehicle_type) LIKE "%whatever%"
```